# How do I swap elements of a 2D array in Scala?

Tags: scala

1. Why does the following code not do the job?
2. How does 'a' get changed after Step 2?
3. What is the best solution to accomplish the task?

   ```
   // 1. Create a 2D array 'a'
   val a = Array.ofDim[String](2, 2)
   a(0)(0) = "TL"
   a(0)(1) = "TR"
   a(1)(0) = "BL"
   a(1)(1) = "BR"

   // 2. Swap two elements of 'a' to create a new 2D array 'b'
   val b = a
   b(0)(0) = a(0)(1)
   b(0)(1) = a(0)(0)

   // Output
   println("a:")
   println(a(0)(0) + " " + a(0)(1))
   println(a(1)(0) + " " + a(1)(1))
   println("b:")
   println(b(0)(0) + " " + b(0)(1))
   println(b(1)(0) + " " + b(1)(1))

   Result:
   a:
   TR **TR**
   BL BR
   b:
   TR **TR**
   BL BR
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy your 2D array like this to create a deep clone:

```
val b = a.map(_.clone)
```

Answer (score 4):

The line:

```
val b = a
```

Does not create a "new" array `b` but just a new reference to the array `a`. So `a` and `b` will point to the same array.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach would be to extend the array class to have a swap method. You could do that as follows:

```
object SwapArray {
  class SwapArrayOp[A](array: Array[A]) {
    def swap(x: Int, y: Int) = {
      val a = array(x)
      array(x) = array(y)
      array(y) = a
    }
  }
  implicit def array2Swap[A](array: Array[A]) = new SwapArrayOp(array)
}
```

Now you can swap values like this:

```
import SwapArray._

val array = Array(Array(1,2), Array(3,4))
array(0).swap(0,1)
println(array) // => Array(Array(2, 1), Array(3, 4))
```

This way you can reuse it and it even looks nicer ;-)